# unnest_wider only if columns exists in R

Tags: r, tidyr, unnest

I would like to `unnest_wider` conditionally depending on whether a column exists in the data. If the column exists, then it should `unnest_wider`, but if not, then it shouldn't do anything. I'd hoped that I could do something like:

```
df1 <- tibble(letters = c('a', 'b', 'c'), values1 = list(1:2, 3:4, 5:6))  

# works
df1 %>% unnest_wider(values1, names_repair = ~gsub('...', 'values1_', ., fixed = TRUE)) 

# doesn't work
df1 %>% unnest_wider(across(any_of("values2")), names_repair = ~gsub('...', 'values1_', ., fixed = TRUE))
```

I know why the last code line doesn't work, but I'd like to accomplish something similar. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like that work:

```
conditional_unnest <- function(df, var){
  if(var %in% names(df)){
    return(unnest_wider(df, var, names_repair = ~gsub('...', 'values1_', ., fixed = TRUE)))
  } else{
    return(df)
  }
}

df1 %>%
  conditional_unnest("values1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method using `tidyr 1.3.1`:

```
df1 %>%
    unnest_wider(
        matches("^values2$"),
        names_repair = ~gsub('...', 'values1_', ., fixed = TRUE)
    )
```